# MySQL Config for server with 8gb RAM and 4 cpus

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a server with 8gb ram and 4 cpus. I don't have enough time for testing and bench marking so I would like to get the advise of experts like you guys, let me know if something is wrong with my mysql config.

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
#connection setting
max_connect_errors      = 10
max_connections         = 400
wait_timeout            = 60
connect_timeout         = 10
interactive_timeout     = 60
#cache setting
query_cache_limit       = 2M
query_cache_size        = 50M
query_cache_type        = 1
table_open_cache        = 5000
thread_cache_size       = 100

#buffer sizes
key_buffer_size         = 20M
sort_buffer_size        = 2M
read_buffer_size        = 2M
join_buffer_size        = 2M

#tmpdir / temp table sizes
tmp_table_size          = 256M
max_heap_table_size     = 256M

#misc. settings
default-storage-engine  = innoDB
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
skip-external-locking
server-id               = 1
open-files-limit        = 65535
max_allowed_packet      = 64M

#innodb settings
innodb_data_file_path     = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_size   = 4G
innodb_log_buffer_size    = 8M
innodb_file_per_table     = 1
log_error               = /var/log/mysql/error.log
log_slow_queries        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time         = 2

#log-queries-not-using-indexes
[mysqldump]
quick
[mysql]
[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: only one wrong - no any information WHAT will do this server? it is not bad, average settings, and it will run sone time good for everything, but for give advise need at least understand - what class of task?  Example - I can give You advice about InnoDB, but You plan use vicidial software, which still work by default on MyISAM ...

Comment: [_Basic Settings_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd agree with comment that asks for "purpose" of the mysql instance though these days you get decent configuration in-built provided with my.cnf.

You should look to use them, my-large/huge/medium.cnf etc...
I see you have query cache and [this link](http://dom.as/tech/query-cache-tuner/) will help you understand best value for it.

Checkout this blog post for [configuring few important parameters](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/28/10-mysql-settings-to-tune-after-installation/).
Finally I'd also like you to review [this config wizard](https://tools.percona.com/wizard).

Again... none of this will give you exact and perfect config... Be ready to monitor and make according changes.